# Trying to concat a string and an int in another column

Tags: python, string, integer, concatenation

I have a problem trying to create a column that is based on another 2 columns.

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 18957585-4 | 3 |
| 14548291-2 | 2 |
| 13553585-8 | 6 |
| 2454841-0 | 21 |
| 48536515-6 | 40 |
| 14548291-2 | 33 |

And I'd like to create a new column that unites these two like this:

| ID | Number | New_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18957585-4 | 3 | 18957585-43 |
| 14548291-2 | 2 | 14548291-22 |
| 13553585-8 | 6 | 13553585-86 |
| 2454841-0 | 21 | 2454841-021 |
| 48536515-6 | 40 | 48536515-640 |
| 14548291-2 | 33 | 14548291-233 |

I tried

```
df['New_Column'] = df['ID'] + str(df['Number'])
```

But that doesn't work and the result is a cell with 4 number, each number in the corner of the cell. If I double click it, it says:
" 2
36     3
Name: ID_Par, dtype: int64"

I also tried

```
df['New_Column'] = str(df['ID']) + str(df['Number'])
```

But that didn't work also. I got the dataframe "df" from an SQL query using pyodbc, if that makes a difference.

I hope someone can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting the numeric column using the [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) method:

```py
df['New_Column'] = df['ID'] + df['Number'].astype(str)
```